# Laravel Migration Foreignkey Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.6 running on:
PHP 7.2,
MariaDB 10.3

When I want to set foreign key for my table, I just keep taking that error.

On other tables, all id variables defined by Laravel itself and auto increments unsigned

So, my Migration is like this:

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('user_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**The error is like this**:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') on delete cascade' at lin
>   e 1 (SQL: alter table `user_roles` add constraint `user_roles_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` () on delete cascade)

**Errors thrown by Laravel**:

> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') on delete cascade' at line 1")
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\order-project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452
>
> 2   PDO::prepare("alter table `user_roles` add constraint `user_roles_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` () on delete cascade")
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\order-project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452

Comment: Other tables / migrations to run properly right? So nothing wrong with the setup?

Comment: try:  `$table->Integer('role_id')->unsigned()`

Comment: Seems like Laravel is ignoring the `->references('id')` for some reason. Without cascade, does it work?

Comment: @utdev Yes, all the other migrations running without any errors.
@AlvaroAlves, I was already tried that and it gives the error like " PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `order-project`.`#sql-3228_8a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")"

@Phiter Nope, it's not working either. By the way, Php Storm says "Method 'references' not found in Illuminate\Support\Fluent" but i think it is about the IDE not about the laravel be cause when i was work with VSC there is no error like that.

Comment: you could just test following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263637/how-to-convert-laravel-migrations-to-raw-sql-scripts this will return your migration query as a raw sql query. Just to be sure that the query is correct

Comment: @utdev
Thanks, i just run that command and tried to run following SQL in my local DB, the error was like this:
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'alter table `user_roles` add constraint `user_roles_role_id_foreign` foreign key' at line 2

SQL: alter table `user_roles` add constraint `user_roles_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`)

Where is the problem? I don't have much knowledge about DB processes.

Comment: Try Composer update or composer dump-autoload Also make sure your foreign table upload after user table in migration table.... Simply try changing order

Comment: @ViperTecPro Thanks for your suggestion, I solved the problem and shared to the below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It fails because of Laravel trying to migrate user_roles table before the roles table. I just migrate roles table before the user_roles table and it's worked! Before the solution rules table is not throwing an error but it's not completely created.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, i got an error like:

General error: 1005 Can't create table `order-project`.`#sql-410_a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Answer (score 0):

I think you have similiar problem with this post [Laravel foreign key onDelete('cascade') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897300/laravel-foreign-key-ondeletecascade-not-working)

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work either. Error is: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Did you change the engine to InnoDB as suggested in the question?