# Translating php laravel sql code to postgres

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am working on rewriting a web app written in `php` and `laravel` to a JavaScript stack. At present I am working on reworking the db schema which seems to be mysql to postgres.

I am slightly confused with some of the syntax for the following `create table` command

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->unique();
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
            $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
            $table->text('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity');
        });
    }
```

From my understanding the `postgres` equivalent for the above would be

```
create table sessions (
    id text unique not null,
    user_id int references users,
    ip_address text,
    user_agent text,
    payload text,
    last_activity integer
    
);
```

However I am not sure that I have translated `$table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();` correctly as I am not sure what exactly `string('ip_address', 45)` is doing.

Is my transformation to potgres correct or what do I need to change in order to have something equivalent in the postgres create command?

Comment: IP addresses shouldn't be stored as a string in Postgres, but with the data type `inet` (and last_activity sounds more like it should be a `timestamp`)

Comment: why... are you not using the migration as god intended? switch the [database driver](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/.env.example#L11), put the creds and db address, then let the migration do it for you. those being said `->string()` can be translated into many things in laravel, you can dig [laravel's github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php) if you want to know.

Comment: fyi, you can declare `inet` column in laravel migration using [`ipAddress`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-ipAddress). it will be translated to `inet` if you set it to run against [tag:postgresql]. though, it will be `nvarchar(45)` for [tag:sql-server] and `varchar(45)` for [tag:mysql].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, for one, leverage `artisan` command's migration as the developer intended. It has been explained in How to convert [Laravel Migrations to Raw SQL Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263637/how-to-convert-laravel-migrations-to-raw-sql-scripts) that you can use:

```
php artisan migrate --pretend
```

However, it has one caveat, you need to have a working database server to actually make it work. It will create `migrations` table (if it doesn't exist) in the target database but it will not create any of the table in the migrations. It will also adhere `migrations` table so you might need to use new database or truncate `migrations` table before running `pretend`.

Alternatively, you can go digging into [Laravel's SQL "Grammar" code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php) and figure things out from there. Sadly, someone is yet to make an easy to read reference table for it.

In your case it translates roughly this way:

| Laravel | Postgre |
| --- | --- |
| `$table->string('id')->unique();` | `id varchar` |
| `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();` | `user_id integer null` |
| `$table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();` | `ip_address varchar(45) null` |
| `$table->text('user_agent')->nullable();` | `user_agent varchar null` |
| `$table->text('payload');` | `payload text` |
| `$table->integer('last_activity');` | `last_activity integer` |

Or rather, written in PostgreSQL:

```
create table sessions (
    id varchar,
    user_id integer null,
    ip_address varchar(45) null,
    user_agent varchar null,
    payload text,
    last_activity integer
);
```

Note:

- There was no directive in the migration to add any foreign keys.
- PostgreSQL does not support unsigned integer, see [Why Unsigned Integer is Not Available in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810134/why-unsigned-integer-is-not-available-in-postgresql).